# How to answer iPhone calls on Android or vice-versa

Tags: android, bluetooth, iphone

I have an Android Device, however, recently I acquired a "work" iOS device. Now even though I have to keep the iPhone on me I would like to leave it in my bag and just forward the calls to my Android, kind of like a Bluetooth headset.

Does this technology exist? Are there any good ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by going to the iOS device's **Settings**, then to **Phone** and tap on **Call Forwarding**, turn that on and input the number you want to forward calls to from your iOS device.

Comment: If your wish to not forward them on iOS there is the new feature  called "Handoff"  which  can auto ring determined devices like a switchboard does..

Comment: @linuxdev2013 did you figure out any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pairing your iPhone with your android device via bluetooth?  that just might give you exactly what you want without having to worry about whether your work calls will get sent to your personal voicemail.